# MongoDB inserting scala Map throws exception

Tags: mongodb, scala

I have a code snippet

```
val dbObj: BasicDBObject = new BasicDBObject("MyMap",map)
//Here Map is a scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int]

dbOps.bulkWrite.find(document).upsert().update(new BasicDBObject("$inc", dbObj))
```

this throws an exception:

**org.bson.codecs.configurtion.CodecConfiguration: Can't find a codec for class scala.collection.immutable.MapLike$$anon$2**

The first thing i noticed is that exception says immutable map while i have a mutable map but i have no idea what's wrong  someone help!

Comment: What's in the "map"? Seems like there is a problem deserializing the key somewhere. Should all be straight text keys or using "dot notation" for nested and plain numbers for the values for a valid argument to `$inc`

Comment: as mentioned in the comment It's a Map[String,Int] so the keys are strings right so i don't think that's the problem